# centos 7 SSL configuration error

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration, centos, restart

I'm getting an error while trying to restart my apache after trying to configure SSL certs on my server by following these steps:

1. running this code

> sudo yum install mod_ssl

2. configuring my ssl.conf as below (all files verified exist at their path location). Only these lines were changed from the default:

   > - DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com"
   > - ServerName www.mydomain.com:443
   > - SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.com.crt
   > - SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.com.key
   > - SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_mydomain.com.crt
3. restart apache
4. Error:

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**Output of 'systemctl status httpd.service':**

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-24 03:20:27 UTC; 14s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 23587 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 19255 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 23586 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 23586 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 24 03:20:27 web kill[23587]: kill: cannot find process ""
Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 24 03:20:27 web systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

**Output of 'journalctl -xe':**

```
Aug 24 03:33:22 web polkitd[352]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23639:84834340 (system bus name :1.905
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 24 03:33:22 web kill[23646]: kill: cannot find process ""
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 24 03:33:22 web systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Aug 24 03:33:22 web polkitd[352]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23639:84834340 (system bus name :1.9
Aug 24 03:34:05 web sudo[23651]:    Nazar : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/httpd/conf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mv ../conf.d/ssl.c
Aug 24 03:34:08 web sudo[23653]:    Nazar : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/httpd/conf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/apachectl start
Aug 24 03:34:08 web polkitd[352]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23656:84838914 (system bus name :1.906
Aug 24 03:34:08 web systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 24 03:34:08 web systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Aug 24 03:34:08 web polkitd[352]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23656:84838914 (system bus name :1.9
Aug 24 03:51:12 web sshd[23811]: Received disconnect from 221.194.47.224: 11:  [preauth]
Aug 24 03:53:38 web sshd[23816]: Received disconnect from 221.194.47.233: 11:  [preauth]
```

**copy of my ssl.conf:**

```
    # When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
    # the HTTPS port in addition.
    #
    Listen 443 https

    ##
    ##  SSL Global Context
    ##
    ##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
    ##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
    ##

    #   Pass Phrase Dialog:
    #   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
    #   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
    #   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
    SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

    #   Inter-Process Session Cache:
    #   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism
    #   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
    SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

    #   Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
    #   Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the
    #   SSL library. The seed data should be of good random quality.
    #   WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
    #   is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
    #   because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
    #   it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
    #   platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
    #   block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
    #   Manual for more details.
    SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
    #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
    #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

    #
    # Use "SSLCryptoDevice" to enable any supported hardware
    # accelerators. Use "openssl engine -v" to list supported
    # engine names.  NOTE: If you enable an accelerator and the
    # server does not start, consult the error logs and ensure
    # your accelerator is functioning properly.
    #
    SSLCryptoDevice builtin
    #SSLCryptoDevice ubsec

    ##
    ## SSL Virtual Host Context
    ##

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

    # General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com"
    ServerName www.mydomain.com:443

    # Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
    # is not inherited from httpd.conf.
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   SSL Protocol support:
    # List the enable protocol levels with which clients will be able to
    # connect.  Disable SSLv2 access by default:
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

    #   SSL Cipher Suite:
    #   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
    #   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

    #   Speed-optimized SSL Cipher configuration:
    #   If speed is your main concern (on busy HTTPS servers e.g.),
    #   you might want to force clients to specific, performance
    #   optimized ciphers. In this case, prepend those ciphers
    #   to the SSLCipherSuite list, and enable SSLHonorCipherOrder.
    #   Caveat: by giving precedence to RC4-SHA and AES128-SHA
    #   (as in the example below), most connections will no longer
    #   have perfect forward secrecy - if the server's key is
    #   compromised, captures of past or future traffic must be
    #   considered compromised, too.
    #SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    #SSLHonorCipherOrder on

    #   Server Certificate:
    # Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
    # the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
    # pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  A new
    # certificate can be generated using the genkey(1) command.
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.com.crt

    #   Server Private Key:
    #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
    #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
    #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
    #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.com.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_mydomain.com.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_mydomain.com.crt

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    #   Per-Server Logging:
    #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    </VirtualHost>
```

Appreciate the help! thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RESOLVED:**

Found the problem by checking the server's ***error_log*** output instead. It was due to the permissions to my cert/key files. I just ran the **'restorecon'** commands on the files and it worked!

Comment: Please explain in more detail how you solved your problem. A quote of used commandlines would be helpful.